# How to find remaining page space using mpdf

Tags: wordpress, fpdf, mpdf

I want to find `remaining page space` for my content. If content cannot comes fit in the page then I want to move the content next page.

Actually i am showing wordpress posts. In the below image the circle is one post but some part is upper and some below page. but I want all this in the below page. 
I am using `mpdf.`

[image]

Comment: Try GetY: http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/gety.htm

Answer (score 2):

us this it will help you

```
$mpdf->_getHtmlHeight($html)
```

Comment: Though this snippet may resolve the immediate issue we prefer to have some context as to how or why it addresses the issue.

Comment: For some reason this information is not documented at the mPDF Github page. 

It works perfectly and solved a very vexing problem for me. 

By adding the value of `$mpdf->_getHtmlHeight` (the size of the block you want to add to your PDF) to the value of `$mpdf->y` (your current position on the y-axis of the page) you can determine if adding the next block of HTML will exceed the remaining available space on the page.

Comment: There are tons of stackoverflow questions about determining the Y position after adding an element and this should be the perfect answer for all of them!!! Didn't know about this utility, thanks, you saved my day... and my sanity!!!

Answer (score 2):

you can use, page breaks

```
page-break-before: always|right|left
```

For more information check [here](https://mpdf.github.io/paging/using-page.html)

Answer (score 1):

The sparsely documented mPDF feature `_getHtmlHeight` (mentioned by [Veenit Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5866617/veenit-kumar)) can be used to determine if your new block of HTML will fit on the page or not.

It is important to wrap your HTML using the conventional standard, or the software may become 'confused' and you will not be able to use the method I am suggesting here to determine your current vertical position on the PDF page:

```
<html><head><style> (css) </style></head><body> (page) </body></html>
```

If you follow this structure, you will be able to determine when you are about to exceed the page's y-axis boundaries.

Submitting HTML one `<tr>` or `<div>` block at a time to mPDF was throwing errors and malforming page layouts for me when I was building a complex table / page.

I found that I had to submit the full page text to `_getHtmlHeight` and `WriteHTML` if I wanted accurate results without errors and problems.

After instantiating mPDF, turn off auto-page break, then set your starting point on the page

```
$mpdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);
$mpdf->SetXY(0,20);
```

Next, place the initial HTML into a PHP string variable:

```
$html_start = '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <!-- Styles -->
    <style type="text/css">
        h1 {font-weight: bold;text-align:center;}
        h2 {font-weight: plain;text-align:center;}
    </style>
  </head>
 <body>
  <h1>User List</h1>
  <h2>'.$userTitle.'</h2>
  <table> 
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>User ID</th>
        <th>Email Address</th>
        <th>User Level</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';
```

Now, place the ending HTML into another PHP variable:

```
$html_footer='
    </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>';
```

Let's assume your process generates HTML code that you want to write to the page, then stores every row's text in an array `$accountData`.

You can determine when the data will overflow the page, by wrapping the page's header & footer around each table row, one row at a time:

```
/*
 *    process table row array
 */
 $html_data_block = '';
 foreach ($accountData as $html_data_line) {
        /*
         *    build temp buffer containing:
         *       page & table header ($html_start) +
         *       accumulated rows already tested ($html_data_block) + 
         *       this detail line ($html_data_line) + 
         *       table & page footer ($html_footer)
         */
         $test_html = $html_start.$html_data_block.$html_data_line.$html_footer;

        /*
         *    will all of this fit on this page?
         */
         if ($mpdf->_getHtmlHeight($test_html) > 259) {
                /*
                 *    NO - so & write page with last $html_data_block that did fit
                 */
                 $html_page_write = $html_page_header.$html_body_header.$html_data_block.$html_footer;
                 $mpdf->WriteHTML($html_page_write);
             
                /*
                 *    next, import a new blank page, set new page position, clear $html_data_block
                 */
                 $pagecount = $mpdf->SetSourceFile('path/to your background.pdf');
                 $mpdf->AddPage();
                 $tplId = $mpdf->importPage($pagecount);
                 $mpdf->useTemplate($tplId);
                 $mpdf->SetXY(0,20);
                 $html_data_block = '';
            }

        /*
         *    append this table row to accumulated rows already tested
         */
         $html_data_block = $html_data_block.$html_data_line;
     }

/*
 *    output accumulated buffer
 */
 $html_page_write = $html_page_header.$html_body_header.$html_data_block.$html_footer;
 $mpdf->WriteHTML($html_page_write);
```

A variation of this process can be used to buffer and trim blocks of text to fit on pages and start new pages as the data fills the available space.

With complicated HTML, `_getHtmlHeight`  may not return an entirely accurate y-axis value. You can end up with pages that break prematurely, leaving unwanted blank space at the bottom of the page.

To resolve this, you must recheck the y-axis current value after `WriteHTML` by comparing `$mPdf->y` to your y-axis limit.

If you recheck the current y-axis and its value is less than your y-limit, don't clear the buffer.

At the next iteration of the foreach loop, just let mPDF rewrite the entire updated buffer over the current generated page.